# 12.10 shutdown/power-up issue

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I have just upgraded to 12.10 on a Shuttle XPC which I use mainly for XBMC and have a problem with shut down/power up. When I shut down from within XBMC the box seems to shut down correctly, but it won't always start again. It hangs before it reaches the point where it mounts the disc's. If I disconnect power shortly and then start up again everything works as it should. It isn't quite repeatable and it does not seem to happen if I exit XBMC and then power down. During power up there seems to be an issue about timing when mounting discs.

What could it be ?